# Use SQL Declare values in a Case Statement. Operands and Integer values will come from a database table

Tags: sql, case, operands

I have a SQL table that stores value inserted by management. I am trying to used the operand values in a Select statement. Management can set values of null, =, >= or <= in the table.

--Get values for LifeCycle D

```
DECLARE @LowerCYSaleValD Int
DECLARE @UpperCYSaleValD Int
DECLARE @LowerOperandValD VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @UpperOperandValD VARCHAR(50)
```

Values being set:

```
SET @LowerCYSaleValD = (SELECT LowerCYSaleVal FROM #LifeCycleFormulas WHERE  LifeCycleAssigned = 'D') 
SET @UpperCYSaleValD = (SELECT UpperCYSaleVal FROM #LifeCycleFormulas WHERE  LifeCycleAssigned = 'D') 
SET @LowerOperandValD = (SELECT LowerOperandVal FROM #LifeCycleFormulas WHERE  LifeCycleAssigned = 'D') 
SET @UpperOperandValD  = (SELECT UpperOperandVal FROM #LifeCycleFormulas WHERE  LifeCycleAssigned = 'D')
```

Values returned:

```
@LowerCYSaleValD  = 50
@UpperCYSaleValD  =  149
@LowerOperandValD  =  >=
@UpperOperandValD  =  <=
```

In my case statement this works:

```
WHEN h.Sales >= 50 AND h.sales <=149 THEN 'D'
```

This works:

```
WHEN h.Sales >= @LowerCYSaleValD AND <= @UpperCYSaleValD THEN 'D'
```

I need to convert this to:

```
WHEN h.Sales @LowerOperandValD @LowerCYSaleValD AND @UpperOperandValD @UpperCYSaleValD THEN 'D'
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't specified exactly which RDBMS platform you are using, but I'm pretty certain there aren't any that will allow a variable to take the place of the operator/s, directly, in the SQL statement.

To be honest, there are probably a number of ways that this proverbial cat could be skinned, but if the possible "operator" values are only >=, <= and =, then a relatively simple approach would be:

```
CASE 
    WHEN 
    (
        (Sales >= @var1 AND @operator1 = '>=')
        OR
        (Sales <= @var1 AND @operator1 = '<=')
        OR
        (Sales = @var1 AND @operator1 = '=')
    )
    AND
    (
        (Sales >= @var2 AND @operator2 = '>=')
        OR
        (Sales <= @var2 AND @operator2 = '<=')
        OR
        (Sales = @var2 AND @operator2 = '=')
    )
    THEN 'D'
    ELSE 'something else'
END
```

Of course, if the different types of operators that the users can choose from may be changed / increased over time, then the CASE statement would have to be altered.  You could potentially wrap the CASE statement in a scalar-valued function (again, dependent on the particular RDBMS that you are using), so that if you need to reference it in multiple different queries, then it's just a case of passing the two "value" variables and the two "operator" variables to the function, and getting the return value.